# How can i play YouTube 360 degrees videos on my Android Application?

Tags: android, video, youtube, 360-degrees

I am unable to get any source to play YouTube 360 degree videos on my android application. I have searched about the Google VR SDK but how to play youtube 360 video through it, i don't know. Looking for some examples or sources to achieve the same.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use the YouTube Android API to play it back (https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) , and if so what happens?

Comment: @Mick When i tried to play it with youtube api, it shows me whole 360 degree view in a single frame.

Answer (score 3):

Google VR SDK's official repository contains sample projects that demo SDK capabilities.  There is a specific sample project that shows how to play a 360deg video (see "sdk-simplevideowidget" project at https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/tree/master/samples).

However, there is no current way to use Google VR SDK to play YouTube videos directly.  You'll either need to package the 360deg videos in your app or stream it from another location that has a direct URL to the video asset.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this Google Developers 'Getting started'](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started#directly_using_gradle)? It also has [a code example](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk).

Also [this Codelabs tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/vr_view_app_101/index.html#0) is a great guide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i went to almost all top tutorials, but its didn't worked for me.